# How to create a binary search tree from a list in erlang

Tags: erlang, binary-search-tree

I'm creating a Propositional Logic Theorem Prover in Erlang, but I'm unable to get my head around parsing a list to a tree.

```
tokenise([]) -> [];

tokenise([$( | T]) -> [{bracket, left}| tokenise(T)];
tokenise([$) | T]) -> [{bracket, right}| tokenise(T)];

tokenise([$& | T]) -> [{logicAnd} | tokenise(T)];
tokenise([$| | T]) -> [{logicOr} | tokenise(T)];
tokenise([$! | T]) -> [{logicNot} | tokenise(T)];

tokenise([X | T]) -> [{prop, X} | tokenise(T)].
```

Input:  `(A!B)`

Current output:

```
[{bracket,left},
 {prop,65},
 {logicNot},
 {prop,66},
 {bracket,right}]
```

Output needed:

```
[ logicNot { A, B } ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to implement your own tree interface instead of use one of the pre-built ones? If you *really* want binary trees instead of [gb_sets](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gb_sets.html) or [gb_trees](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gb_trees.html) you may find inspiration in a [binary tree implementation](https://gist.github.com/d11wtq/5212699) on github.

Comment: `[ logicNot { A, B } ]` is not valid Erlang term

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are creating your own logic language via scanning and parsing. Have you looked at [leex](http://erlang.org/doc/man/leex.html) and [yecc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/yecc.html) in the Erlang standard library to do this for you? (A good tutorial can be found [here](https://arifishaq.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/playing-with-leex-and-yeec/))

### Scanner

Using leex, you can write a scanner in the file `test_scanner.xrl` as follows:

```
Definitions.

W = [a-zA-Z0-1]

S = [\s\t\n\r\f\v\d]

Rules.

{W}+ : {token, {prop, TokenChars, TokenLine}}.
\(   : {token, {'(', TokenLine}}.
\)   : {token, {')', TokenLine}}.
\!   : {token, {'!', TokenLine}}.
{S}+ : skip_token.

Erlang code.
```

Compile it:

```
$ erlc test_scanner.xrl # This produces an normal Erlang file
$ erlc test_scanner.erl # This compiles the actual beam file
```

Use it:

```
1> l(test_scanner).
{module,test_scanner}
2> {ok, Tokens, _EndLine} = test_scanner:string("(a ! b) ! c").
{ok,[{'(',1},
     {prop,"a",1},
     {'!',1},
     {prop,"b",1},
     {')',1},
     {'!',1},
     {prop,"c",1}],
    1}
```

### Parser

Using yecc, you can write a parser in the file `test_parser.yrl` as follows:

```
Terminals prop '!' '(' ')'.

Nonterminals expr.

Rootsymbol expr.

Left 100 '!'.

expr -> '(' expr ')' : '$2'.
expr -> expr '!' expr : {logicNot, '$1', '$3'}.
expr -> prop : prop('$1').

Erlang code.

prop({prop, Name, _Line}) -> Name.
```

Compile it:

```
$ erlc test_parser.yrl # This produces an normal Erlang file
$ erlc test_parser.erl # This compiles the actual beam file
```

Use it:

```
3> test_parser:parse(Tokens).
{ok,{logicNot,{logicNot,"a","b"},"c"}}
```

### Result

This gives you a simple binary tree structure based on tuples:

```
{logicNot,
    {logicNot,
        "a",
        "b"},
    "c"}}
```

Comment: I appreciate you putting your time and effort into this answer, sadly I cannot use leex and yecc, I can only use the basic functionalities of erlang to do it, and that's the confusing part as it's hard to find any help to do it.

Comment: Leex and Yecc are in the standard library, why can't you use them?

Answer (score 2):

You currently have a lexer recognizing tokens, but you lack a parser that recognizes valid sequences of tokens and reduces them based on grammar rules. I suggest you look into using [`leex`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/leex.html) to construct your lexer and [`yecc`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/yecc.html) to construct your parser.

Answer (score 1):

Your output is what I would call syntactic analysis. You have transformed your input into a normalized, tree form which produced a syntactically correct expression in your language.

Next take that output and recursively walk it constructing the target output.

By the way, I would suggest that you change you operators to be a 2-tuple of {Op, operator} - {Op, logicNot}, for example. I think you will find it easier to write the next phase if you do.

So as a hint (this code is NOT good),

```
do([]) -> 
   "";
do({prop,C}) ->
  [C];

do([{bracket,left} | Tl]) ->
   lists:append(["[ ", do(Tl),"] "]);

do([A, {logicNot}|Tl]) ->
  lists:append(["logicNot { ", do(A), ",", do(Tl), " }"]);

do([{prop, C}, {bracket, right}]) ->
  [C].
```

Basically, you are going to write a a recursive method, p, that maps things like [{ A Op B}] to [Op {p(A), p(B)}]...